reading cosmos json document into 1 column in a table with ADF
I wanna read cosmos-documents in ADF with copy data.
I know how to map to different columns.
I would like to put the entire document into 1 column.
Its easy to read a nested array into 1 column through mapping but is it possible to map the entire document into 1 column?
sample json data "id": "12345-6789", "stamp": "2024-09-10 09:34", "nested" [ { "year": 2024, "month": 09, "value": 10 }, { "year": 2024, "month": 08, "value": 5 } ] I need to use copy data or data flow to copy that into a single column i an ms sql table so the contents of the table has the entire json document. I know how to select an array inside a jsondocument with cosmos query into a single mapping. But how to get the entire document

can you add sample input output? and what you have tried?

what is your destination?

Please edit to provide a [mcve] with all relevant detail. As written, there's no way to provide any answer. Right now, all you provided is a high level description of something you're trying to achieve, but with no code, no data, behavior/errors...

sample json data
"id": "12345-6789",
"stamp": "2024-09-10 09:34",
"nested" [
{
"year": 2024,
"month": 09,
"value": 10
},
{
"year": 2024,
"month": 08,
"value": 5
}
]
I need to use copy data or data flow to copy that into a single column i an ms sql table so the contents of the table has the entire json document.
I know how to select an array inside a jsondocument with cosmos query into a single mapping. But how to get the entire document

@Alan - please edit your question - data and code needs to be properly formatted to be readable, and that can't be done in a comment.


is it possible to map the entire document into 1 column?

You cannot directly map the entire document into single column you need use the openjson table-valued function that parses JSON text follow the below approach.

Take a Lookup activity, and add cosmosdb as dataset in the activity.



Then the output of the lookup activity is stored in the variable named  json  of string type using set variable.

@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)



In Script activity add linked service for Azure SQL database and add below Script:

declare @json nvarchar(4000)=N'@{variables('Json')}';
INSERT INTO test_tgt
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
col1 nvarchar(max) '$' AS JSON
);

This script will insert the data into the table  test_tgt  which is already created.

SQL table output


Please don't answer off-topic questions. The OP has shown no work, so you are essentially authoring a custom solution based on nothing but a high level requirement (and not answering any specific question). And that's not what Stack Overflow is for. I explicitly commented under the question, asking the OP to provide their details (as did you), which they still haven't done, aside from a comment containing more description and a tiny bit of (unformatted) data). Also: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I have added the information. And it was more a generel question than a specific solution i was looking for. Anyway i cant use the above solution and already use similar solutions in other pipelines. I will accept the above solution since it seems what i need is not possible. And how is it offtopic?

After some trial and error i finally figured out how to do what i needed.
The cosmosquery just have to look like this. Pretty simple
SELECT c.id, c AS rawjson FROM c
Then you get 2 columns you can map in a "copy data"-activity. The ID is just for information so is not needed if you just want the raw json-document.
